# Batch file not displaying error when no filename exists

Tags: batch-file, command-line, copy

I am freshly new to batch and just curious why my .bat file takes input, but does not display an error or anything else, it just closes. Maybe its something i missed. Thanks!

```
@echo off



REM Clear the screen
REM ------------------------------------------------------
cls


REM Getting user input
REM ------------------------------------------------------
SET /p FilesToCopy="Please enter a file to copy!: "


REM 1. Copies files to myTemp
REM ------------------------------------------
IF EXIST "%FilesToCopy%" (

  xcopy %FilesToCopy% C:\myTemp /E

  ECHO FILE [%FilesToCopy%] are being copied!

REM 2. Displays error if not found
REM ------------------------------------------
) ELSE (

  ECHO Sorry but there was a issue copying [%FilesToCopy%]..

)
```

Comment: Are you running through a click of the mouse or in a proper command prompt window? Also: have you tried commenting out your first line? Cause `echo off` is intended to not echo anything.

Comment: Tried both through cmd prompt and mouse. Also tried echo on/off and commented out. It just takes the input no matter what and quits.

Comment: Have bad (or good) news for you: here your code worked perfectly. Windows 10. Are you logged as admin? The app requested a file (i pointed one at the same folder level), it asked about **myTemp** being a file or folder, copied and confirmed the operation.

Comment: Hmm same here windows 10, logged in as admin, the only way I can see the error is by adding pause at the end of the batch file, should this be the case?

Comment: I didn't put pause or anything: run the exactly provided code. If a file exists it does copies. if a file pointed to copy does not exists (or if none) it displays the error `Sorry but there was a issue copying`. Am i miss something?

Comment: No thats exactly what should happen, but for whatever reason mine just closes, never shows any of the echos, so weird

Comment: Figured it out, seems to be that I have to run it off my desktop, its connected to a cloud folder which seems to screw with it for whatever reason! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice! I was just writing that this could be far from my knowledge eheh... May I ask you something, please? Answer your own question and check it as the correct one: this instruct people with same (or almost) problems thus mark the question as answered, avoiding people to enter here trying to answer - this is the recommended practice here at S.O. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Your post lacks the evidence that you ever ran your script.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I was not running batch file from a local folder and through the cmd prompt itself.